# How to create a WordPress widget with options that can be edited

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to create a custom WordPress widget that will consist of a pair of buttons. Each button will link to a different location. I only need to be able to edit the title and `href` of each button when dropping the widget into a sidebar.

I've created custom widget areas already, and know how to implement those and have followed a couple of tutorials to create custom widgets, but cannot seem to understand how to make options editable.

Here is an example of the code that will be output by the widget:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
<a class="mycustombutton" href="#" target="_blank">Text Here</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
<a class="mycustombutton" href="#" target="_blank">Text Here</a> 
</div>
```

Ideally, I could use this widget anywhere on the site to add these buttons but would be able to change the `href` of the buttons as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to WordPress, you can use Widget Generators like [this one](https://www.wp-hasty.com/tools/wordpress-widget-generator/) for now and then study the code it generates to see how it works.

You can also look at the Widgets [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) to create custom widgets.

Comment: Thanks so much for the Widget Generator site. Extremely useful. I created a simple widget using the Generator, then used the WordPress Widget docs/API to learn how to configure the output for what I needed. I actually created exactly the widget I was after and it only took a couple days to perfect and implement.